# TensorFlow tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul

Tags: python, c++, matrix, tensorflow

I run a small experiment to benchmark the tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul operation. Unfortunately, I am surprised by the result.

I am running a sparse matrix, dense vector multiplication, and vary

- the number of columns of the sparse matrix (decreasing)
- the number of rows of the dense vector (decreasing)
- the sparsity of the sparse matrix (increasing)

While increasing the sparsisy for each run, I decrease the columns. This means that the number of non-zero values (nnz) stays always the same (100 per row).

When measuring the time needed for computing the matml operation, I would expect, that it will stay the same (since the output size nor the nnz varies).

What I see instead is the following:
[image]

I looked into the C++ code to see if I can spot any reasons for the result. Though, also taking the C++ code into account I would expect the same time for each run. If I understand the code right, it loops through all nnz values of the sparse matrix (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul_op.cc#L239). For each nnz value it loops through all columns of the second dense matrix (in my case it is only one column since it is a vector) (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul_op.cc#L245).

The only point where I could imagine that the number of rows of the second matrix/vector effects the performance is https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/sparse_tensor_dense_matmul_op.cc#L246 if it loops through all the rows of the second matrix/vector insight the "maybe_adjoint_b" function to get to the currently needed row.

[What disturbs me about the "maybe_adjoint_b" call is, that it gets called with the variable "k" passed over as the row index. Though, I thought "m" would be the row index and "k" the column index of the sparse matrix.]

**Question:** Why do I get different execution times for the matmul operation, even though the nnz and the output sizes are always the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that it is not an issue of TensorFlow but instead the 8MB input of the input vector in the first case does not fit into the L2 memory. In all the other cases the vector is <= 800kb and fits into the L2 memory.